# getView(Unknown Source) on some devices with Android 2.3.4-2.3.6

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-2.3-gingerbread, device

My app seems to crash for no valid reason on some devices with older Android OS and works just fine on all others.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater vi;

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.general_contact_item_layout, null, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactImage);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        holder.txtName.setTextSize(18);

        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    final Contact contact = contacts.get(position);

    if (contact != null) {
        if (contact.contactID != null)
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contact.contactID));
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        if (contact.name != null && contact.name.length() > 0)
            holder.txtName.setText(contact.name);
        else
            holder.txtName.setText("(No Name)");
        holder.imageView.setImageURI(null);
        if (contact.photoUri != null)
            holder.imageView.setImageURI(contact.photoUri);

    }
    return v;
}
```

Here is the Stacktrace from my ArrayAdapter:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.android.cc.clean.ui.a.getView(Unknown Source)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1539)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1794)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:719)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1351)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1390)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1145)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is that this error seems to have it´s source somewhere else.

Affected devices are for example:

- ONE TOUCH 4007D
- GT-I9070
- GT-S5360
- GT-I9000

Is there any known issue which causes this problem?

Comment: The code seems obfuscated and the debugging information is removed. But it's still your `getView()` where the NPE is.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm your problem with the getView function. However, you listed just samsung devices. While developing my last App for Android 2.2+, i encountered heavy problems, accessing original Android resources like Time/Date Picker Dialog Layouts and so on. Those problems only appeared on older TouchWiz (Samsung) devices. That makes me believe, Samsung removed a couple of files from Stock Android in order to create TouchWiz. Try to fall back, to other methods.
--edit: a snippet of your code might help, finding a solution.

--edit2: I uploaded an old ArrayAdapter of my last project. It doesn't follow Androids recycling guidelines by 100% but still runs pretty fast. That should guide you how to identify the convertView. [download](http://euve22325.vserver.de/ArrayAdapter.java)

It's supposed to use standard components and header/additional views (ea accessory buttons) without need of Extended or expandableListView.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but I found another device, it´s an Alcatel ONE TOUCH 4007D. But it´s the only not Samsung in my list

Comment: I can only guess. You may try, using and returning the convertView instead of your newly created view. The ViewHolder Pattern seems to be fine. Also i've never used null as value for an ImageURI. Personally i rather like using supers getView function instead of inflating the view by myself. `
  View result;
  if (convertView == null) {
   result = super.getView(position, null, parent);
  } else if (
    (convertView.getId() == mTextViewResourceId)) {
   result = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  } else {
   result = super.getView(position, null, parent);
  }`

Comment: Thank you, implemented it now and it works. Now I´ll push the update and just see what will happen, sadly I´ve no other choice

Comment: If I use the app in landscape mode, it crashes with java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView. and IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView .responsible is this line v = super.getView(position, null, viewGroup); any workaround for that?

Comment: Yep, check if the convertView is instanceof TextView, then give it to super.getView, elseway use null instead. --edit: a crash upon rotating the device most likely happens, because the Activity gets restarted in that case. You may prevent that behaviour using the android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" meta in Android Manifest, for your Activity.

Comment: I already use this config for my activity, but I´ll try the null passing. Thank you